# Testing Queries in ExUnit for a library

Tags: testing, elixir, ecto

I am testing queries(`not the data returned from queries`) in the ExUnit for this library.

https://github.com/tanweerdev/fat_ecto

Here is my code:

```
 test "returns the query where field like" do
   opts = %{
    "$where" => %{"first_name" => %{"$like" => "%Ham %"}}
   }

   assert build(QM.Test.Model, opts) ==
 end
```

The result the function  returned in the console is this:

```
 left:  #Ecto.Query<from m in QM.Test.Model,
         where: like(m.first_name, ^"%Ham %")>
```

The main goal here is to see if the `build` function is building queries correctly.

I am not testing ecto. I am testing the function which builds the query

How can I insert this result in the right `to make the tests pass`.

Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to go about testing this logic? It kinda tests the internals `Ecto.Query` and couples it very closely to how it works, which makes it very brittle when you update `Ecto`.

Comment: it doesnt look to be a good approach... you're testing ecto internals (which are already tested) - if you update/move away from Ecto all your tests will break

Comment: @SaschaWolf I am not testing ecto. I am testing my function `build`. which builds up the query. I am testing if its building the query right.

Comment: @script I understand that but your test depends on the internal implementation of `Ecto.Query`. As such your test will break when Ecto changes the implementation, even if the business logic still is correct. That is what I meant when I said you test Ecto.

Comment: @SaschaWolf of course this lib will be dependent on ecto versions and will take care of updates

Comment: The thing is, with the approach on top your tests can break on any version change - even a bug fix one (so it might break from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4). Basing your tests on internal logic will do that. But only using public APIs should keep your tests stable for all releases except major ones (so 1.2.3 to 2.0.0). This is given due to the fact that Ecto is using semantic versioning.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to check the resulting SQL using [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#to_sql/3):

```
assert Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(
  :all, repo, build(QM.Test.Model, opts)
) == {"SELECT ... WHERE first_name LIKE '$1'", ["%Ham %"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please take a look at the question again. I updated it. May be you can give better suggestion about the solution.

Comment: I think mudasobwa's suggestion should be enough to answer your question, what are you missing to solve your problem?

Comment: @script I did not find any significant changes in the question. Also, the task itself, as you were told a couple of times already, seems to be sorta XY problem. You are indeed testing `Ecto`. FYI, **[`Ecto.Query`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/query.ex#L291) is a struct**. If you want to have “a better solution” (whatever it means,) you might examine fields of this struct, which are related to what you wanted to test explicitly, one by one.

Comment: I would refrain from testing internal fields and even testing the generated SQL query. Such tests can break at any time, a small bugfix release might change the internal logic and leave you with a broken test suite. Stable tests can be achieved by only relying on public API.

Answer (score 0):

The least brittle approach to testing query generation would be to create the query you're expecting "by hand" in the test.

One such test could look like this:

```
expected_query = from m in QM.Test.Model, where: like(m.first_name, "%Ham %")
opts = %{
  "$where" => %{"first_name" => %{"$like" => "%Ham %"}}
}

assert build(QM.Test.Model, opts) == expected_query
```

This obviously still couples your tests to `Ecto`. But it will ensure your tests don't break on the smallest version change. Only a major release should result in breaking tests but such a release would then also result in a broken application, which in turn makes the point moot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I already tried this. its not working for me